# How to handle error message `lualatex-math.sty' not found?

Tags: luatex

I wan't to compile the following latex-code within Texstudio on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
    
    \[
    ¬q→ ¬p→q
    \]
    
    \[
    \neg q\rightarrow \neg p\rightarrow q
    \]
    
\end{document}
```

the output should be as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72764353/convert-string-with-unicode-characters-e-g-%E2%86%92-%E2%88%A7-%C2%AC-into-strings-illustrated-in-la/72764383#72764383) post. Unfortunately I get the following error messages:

```
File `lualatex-math.sty' not found. \cs_set_protected:Npn
Font \TU/lmr/bx/n/10=[lmroman10-bold]:+tlig; at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad. \strongfontdeclare{ \bfseries }
Font \TU/lmr/m/n/10=[lmroman10-regular]:+tlig; at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad. ...lt\familydefault\seriesdefault\shapedefault
```

how can I solve that? I searched for lualatex-math.sty in google, but I can't find this file.

```
which lualatex
```

brings

```
/usr/bin/lualatex
```

Comment: Let me guess you installed texlive via apt? Install `apt-file`, run `sudo apt-file update` and then use `apt-file search lualatex-math.sty` to figure out which ubuntu package provides that file.

Comment: After that command the terminal gives: `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/lualatex-math/lualatex-math.sty`. What now to do? I am pretty new in latex sorry.

Comment: Are you sure you gave the full output? I get (Ubuntu 18.04) `texlive-luatex: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/lualatex-math/lualatex-math.sty` meaning I'd need to install the Ubuntu package `texlive-luatex` in order to get `lualatex-math.sty`. Sadly Ubuntu split TeXLive  into several Ubuntu packages which makes it very confusing what you n3eed to install. Thus my recommendation of the `apt-file` tool.

Comment: Ok, after installing `texlive-luatex` with `sudo apt install texlive-luatex` it works now.  Tanks for the help ...